# Difference between command `ls 2 >tmp >tmp` and command `ls > tmp`

Tags: shell

I don't understand what is the difference b/w `ls 2>tmp >tmp` and `ls > tmp`. They both seem to do essentially the same thing, creating a file tmp and storing the result of `ls` command.

Comment: You seem to be asking two separate questions here.

Comment: `ls >2 >tmp1 >tmp1` doesn't appear to be a valid command.

Comment: You are basically with the `ls >2 > tmp1 > tmp1` script command taking the command `ls` sending the output to a file named `2` (if it is not there create it) which doesn't write to the file `2`, but sends it to a file `tmp1` (if it is not there create it), does not write to `tmp1`, but sends that output to `tmp1` (if it is not there create it), then the output settles in `tmp1`. tl;dr You make a blank file `2` have an extra `> tmp1` and output `ls` to `tmp1`. (Could you split this into 2 questions as well?)

Comment: @NoTime I have updated the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A short answer: `ls 2>tmp >tmp` redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to file `tmp`. while `ls > tmp` only redirect `stdout` to file `tmp`.

Try this to see the difference:

```
$ ls asdsadasd 2>tmp >tmp
$ cat tmp
ls: cannot access asdsadasd: No such file or directory

$ ls asdsadasd > tmp
ls: cannot access asdsadasd: No such file or directory
$ cat tmp
<Nothing happen here>
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that you should not do:

```
ls 2> tmp > tmp
```

Above the shell opens `tmp` for writing on file descriptor 2, then it opens `tmp` for writing again on file descriptor 1 and then executes `ls`. You'll have two [file descriptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) pointing to two separate open file descriptions to the same file.

If `ls` writes on both its file descriptor 1 (stdout for the file list) and file descriptor 2 (stderr for the error messages), those outputs will overwrite each other (assuming `tmp` is a regular file and not a named pipe).

Actually, the stdout output will be buffered, so is more likely to be written at the end before `ls` exits, so it will overwrite the stderr output.

Example:

```
$ ls /x /etc/passwd 2> tmp > tmp
$ cat tmp
/etc/passwd
ccess /x: No such file or directory
```

You should use:

```
ls > tmp 2>&1
```

or

```
ls 2> tmp >&2
```

In that case, the shell opens `tmp` on fd 2 and then duplicates that fd onto fd 1, so both fd 1 and 2 will share the same open file description to `tmp` and outputs won't overwrite each other.

```
$ ls /x /etc/passwd 2> tmp >&2
$ cat tmp
ls: cannot access /x: No such file or directory
/etc/passwd
```